# PHP creating websocket results in Permission denied

Tags: php, websocket

I am using [this](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket/tree/master/server/lib/WebSocket) PHP websocket library to connect to a non secured websocket server. On localhost using XAMPP it is working fine. I can create the server and connect to it succesfully on the client side with JavaScript using

> new WebSocket('ws://mywebsite.com:80/dashboard');

However, now I want to create the websocket at a live http site (cpanel shared host). I have access to the SHELL but I can not create/open ports, so I have to use the default port 80 to create the websocket server on.

Now the problem is when executing the PHP file on the SHELL to create the websocket server, this error I get: `PHP Warning:  stream_socket_server(): unable to connect to tcp://www.mywebsite.com:80 (Permission denied)`

> php [public_html/websocket/server.php](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket/blob/master/server/server.php)

Does someone know why it says permission denied since port is always open.

```
$this->context = stream_context_create();
stream_socket_server("tcp://www.mywebsite.com:80", $errno, $err, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $this->context)
```

I have the feeling something is wrong with 'stream_context_create()' at [Socket.php](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket/blob/master/server/lib/WebSocket/Socket.php). Is that possible or do you know a other reason why I am not able to create the websocket server?

Answer (score 0):

By default ports below 1024 can be opened only by root. Root access is not allowed by most of shared hosting providers.

You can check which ports above 1024 are open and start your server in one of them.

An alternative is to move to a VPS, you can have cheap instances in [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) or even in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (free tier instances)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I don't want a vps because starting a websocket server on port 80 on a shared host should be possible right? Actually using PHP's `stream_socket_client ` function creates succesfully a server on the shared host, but then a other problem occurs: I can't connect to the server using the javascript function mentioned in the first post. I really don't know whats wrong in this case...

Comment: @Piet Didn't you say in your post that you get a permission denied?, Did you work around that issue?

Comment: That's right. So the be clear, there are 2 situations. The first one is when I am using `stream_socket_server`, this will result in a permission denied. The second situation is when I use `stream_socket_client` instead of 'stream_socket_server', in this situation the PHP socket server is running fine, but still I can't connect to the server with Javascript (it will trow a 302 error in the developers console of the browser).

Comment: @Piet but are you trying to connect to your server websocket or to a third party websocket, because if you're trying to connect to your websocket server when you couldn't start the server that won't work, I'm a little confused...

Comment: Let's spam a little bit here so SO will create a chat where you can explain the problem a little bit further

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear, I tried to explain the whole situation here https://pastebin.com/RSZbNB6t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142366/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-piet).